# How to wrap text in circle in d3

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create split bubble chart.In this i need to show city names on each bubble.So far I am pretty much able achieve this apart from one thing,that I am not able to wrap text inside bubbles.

I am adding text to circles with following code-

```
circles1.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "gFontFamily")
      .style("font-size", '11px')
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.year;
      });
```

Clearly to truncate text to fit inside circle, I need radius of the circle at the time when I am adding the text.So that on the basis of that I can take some substring from the actual text and print it after adding '..'

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob7yzww6/32/)

Any help is appreciated.Thanx

Comment: This example may help you. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: you need to split the text to create multiple text tags. svg doesnt support text wrapping

Comment: The link @murli2308 provided should be very helpful. In order to get the radius, it may be easier to use `circles1.each (function() {var r = d3.select(this).attr("r"); d3.select(this).append("text").text(function (d){return wrap(d.Store, r)})...})` to append the text.

Comment: Are you sure you want to wrap the text? City names can be long, without any word breaks to necessarily wrap. I'd consider scaling the text down instead....

Comment: If you're able to implement this view with absolutely-positioned HTML divs instead of SVGs (which might sound crazy but actually a reasonable, simple approach) then you'll get wrapping and ellipses for "free". See this [Proof of Concept](https://jsfiddle.net/t2vg5x58/)

Comment: @Ian I think I chose the wrong word 'wrap' .Actually what I want to do is to truncate my text manually and add .. at the end when needed. For this I need the radius of the circle at the time of adding the text,which i am not able to get!

Comment: @meetamit Plz see above